# Clone a datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I'm trying to clone a datepicker a week ago and when I get it or the clone function does not work, or the datepicker function, I hope they can help me! Thank you

Remove the code from a blog

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
            var num     = $('.clonedInput').length;
            var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);

            var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

            newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
            $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');

        if (newNum == 5)
            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').click(function() {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

        $('#input' + num).remove();
        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');

        if (num-1 == 1)
            $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
</script>
```

Próximos Pasos

```
      <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="x"  class="btn btn-default"/>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="+" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </div>
```

```
     <div class="col-md-4">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="proximospasos1" name="proximospasos1" required value="" placeholder="Próximos Pasos">
    </div>



     <div class="col-md-4">

   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="participantes1" name="participantes1" required value=""  placeholder="Participantes">
      </div>

  <div class="col-md-2">

          <div class="input-group date">
           <input type="text" class="form-control date" id="fecha2" name="fecha2"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
             <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
             </div>
             </div>
          </span>
```

```
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

change this line:

```
var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
```

To this:

```
var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().datepicker().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
```